# Quest objectives not updating, even though the quest is already completed

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Are there any console commands or mods that can fix this?

I tried these commands:

- `setobjectivecomplete cwobj 1002 1`
- `setobjectivecomplete cwobj 102 1`

But they didn’t work :(

[image]

It's for the “Liberate Haafingar” and “Report to Ulfric Stormcloak” objectives.

Comment: Are you using any mods, and, if so, can you tell us which they are?

Comment: Also: how long has it been since you completed the quest? Have you tried waiting for a long time, fast-travelling, doing other quests first, &c.?

Comment: Nope no mods. It’s been two days and I just realised but I guess if it’s a common bug then it’s fine. Thank you bro

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems to be a common bug, specifically when it comes to liberating Haafingar, as the [UESP](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Liberation_of_Skyrim) mentions these two items by name:

> The "Liberate Haafinger" and "Report to Ulfric Stormcloak" objectives will not be marked as completed in the quest log once the quest is complete.

It doesn't mention a solution.
However, a Reddit user, experiencing the exact same problem, [mentions](https://www.reddit.com/r/SkyrimHelp/comments/o4fzk/liberate_haafingarstormcloak_glitchsolution/) a workaround that worked for them. The idea is to force the next step by going to Solitude:

> Enter Solitude anyway. Your orders would have been to join the men and attack Solitude. When you enter the city, Ulfric, Galmar, and the rest of the Stormcloaks, magically appear behind you and trigger the battle.